# Unable to style ActionBar items in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

I am trying to change the colour of an `ActionItem` within the Nativescript framework. I have tried setting both the `color` and `background-color` inline and within my `.css` file, but this has no effect.

My XML for the ActionBar:

```
<ActionBar title="Activities">
    <ActionBar.actionItems>
        <ActionItem
          ios.systemIcon="13" ios.position="left"
          android.systemIcon="ic_menu_refresh" android.position="actionBar"/>
    </ActionBar.actionItems>
</ActionBar>
```

My CSS for the Actionbar:

```
ActionBar{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000165; 
}
```

I have also tried using:

```
ActionItem{
    color: #fff; 
    background-color:#fff
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't style the system icons with CSS. You could use custom images in place of them and style them prior to using in your app. There are limitations on the platforms for the `<ActionBar.actionItems>`, check the repo for some more info, I believe there was an issue related to this not long ago.